# The shape of the hyperbolic curves coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, hyperbolic-geometry

Any one has an idea about hyperbolic coordinates ? and how to  imagine it ?
Indeed I am trying to find the  shape of the coordinate curves far away from origin ! and what is the shape of them at $u=0 , v=0,v=3.14/2$ and $v= 3.14$ 
[see this photo which disply how the hyperbolic coordinates defined by the cartesian coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvnUV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Set $\phi = 0$ in the first three equations. Then $y = 0$ and you are left with two equations in the $xz$ plane.

Wikipedia calls these "[Elliptic coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system)".

Comment: it's very useful so they r the Elliptic coordinates .Thx